# Find a specific string in HTML or JavaScript

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I would like to get some text of html page I'm navigating It's a program version numbers

```
"(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)" The regex code.
```

I want to execute this command in webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted

Something like this

> string html = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
>
> ```
>             // scrape keywords
>             version = Regex.Match(html, @"""(\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)""",
> ```
>
> RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[0].Value;

Which doesn't seem to work. (The text I'm trying to find isn't in body or any place specified I need just grab the whole html code and find it there)

I can confirm this what is not working is the way I get HTML text, I need alternative way because there is no  or body or anything I just need the whole webbrowser text and use the regex (Regex works fine I think)

Comment: Are you trying to scrape an IP address?

Comment: program version example: 3.4.2.6

Comment: Seen as you've got the `@` symbol, you don't need to escape your slashes (e.g. @"""(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)""")

Comment: Also, I've just noticed, you should only use one pair of quotes. `"""` is a Python thing, mainly.

Comment: @Fodaro if I use one pair of quotes I get errors all ever the place (it will not debug have to use 2 pair) I tried without slashes nothing I think the code doesn't really work.

Comment: Mark could you please make it clear in your question: do you have problem with regular expression OR with getting text from browser control? Your question's title seem to imply problem with RegEx, but comments make it more like getting text issue...

Comment: Is it placed inside an element with an `id` attribute? If it is you can use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<the_id>")` to get the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RegEx `\d\.?` will match the version number in this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <span>3.4.2.6</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Bear in mind that there are four matches returned so when using it you'll need to get the entire match instead of individual groups.

So, you might use it like this:

```
var version = RegEx.Match(html, @"\d\.?").Value;
```

Another possible RegEx that's more specific too would be `((\d\.){3}\d{1})`. This RegEx will capture the specific version number twice in the following string, HTML or JavaScript, doesn't matter. But it will ignore the `3.4.2`.

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <span>3.4.2.6</span> 
    3.4.2
</body> 
</html> 

function(){
    var test = "something";
    var version = "3.4.2.6"
}
```

To retrieve the text of the web page the `WebBrowser` control is currently on try the following code in the `DocumentCompleted` event handler:

```
var html = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

Comment: thanks! and what if it's not in the body? It's in the HTML there but there are no <body>

Comment: @MarkVoidale, that shouldn't be a problem. I just wrapped it in HTML to prove it didn't matter what was around it.

Comment: @MarkVoidale, I added another possible RegEx for you that is more specific. So, if there was a `1.2` in the HTML somewhere it would **not** pick that up.

Comment: It's not even inside HTML it's a lot of JavaScript codes no def of HTML or Body or anything will still it work? And the regex doesn't seem to catch it they got many digits...

Comment: @MarkVoidale, please see my edit, the other RegEx I gave you should be able to catch it more specifically. And HTML vs. JavaScript doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 (both RegEx answers) to answering question as asked and providing alternative RegEx (also I suspect it has nothing to do with what Mark have problem with).

Comment: I can confirm this what is not working is the way I get HTML text, I need alternative way

Comment: @BigM you're the best keep helping me :) Hmm I just tried some random regex like (.*) but the problem is my MessageBox is empty (Just for testing) all is empty can never get anything. The way I get the string html is bad...

Comment: @MarkVoidale, is the value you're looking for actually in the HTML of the web page that the `WebBrowser` control is currently on?

Comment: @BigM I used fiddler in the text view and saw the program version in there it's the html I pretty sure.

Comment: @BigM You're right I just did view source and this is the problem!!

Comment: @MarkVoidale, alright, see my edit and try accessing the text of the document as I stated at the end of the answer. Make ***sure*** you access the `DocumentText` property from the ***`DocumentCompleted`*** event.

Comment: @MarkVoidale, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18243/discussion-between-mark-voidale-and-bigm)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `@"(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)"` should match and capture the whole version number, whereever it is in the HTML.